# SVG element not coming inside a DIV

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to display an svg line inside div. The position is given to the DIV so i am expecting the line to be placed inside div as child element but it is coming under it, as if it is outside div. Following is my code:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:246pt; left:6pt; width:581.976pt; height:3pt; border:1px solid blue"> 
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  version="1.1" width="581.976pt" height="3pt" style="border:1px solid black">
        <line id = "default" x1="0pt" y1="1.5pt" x2="581.976pt" y2="0pt" style="stroke:rgb(229,52,52); stroke-width:3pt;stroke-dasharray:10, 5"/> 
    </svg> 
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qL5p74xL/)

I am trying to find the reason for a long time now but unable to understand this behavior. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put `float:left;` or `display: block;` to the svg element.

```html
<div style="position:absolute; top:246pt; left:6pt; width:581.976pt; height:3pt; border:1px solid blue"> 
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  version="1.1" width="581.976pt" height="3pt" style="border:1px solid black; float:left;">
    <line id = "default" x1="0pt" y1="1.5pt" x2="581.976pt" y2="1.5pt" style="stroke:rgb(229,52,52); stroke-width:3pt;stroke-dasharray:10, 5"/> 
    </svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you both methods work. Can you please tell which is the better one?

Comment: @AbdulJabbar Display block probably makes more sense, unless text is meant to flow around it.

Comment: Both should work fine. But as @AlexanderO'Mara said, `display: block;` makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the SVG is overflowing the DIV, mainly due to SVG elements being `display: inline;` by default. This can easily be fixed by adding a display property to the SVG's styles, such as `display: block;`.

```html
<div style="position:absolute; top:246pt; left:6pt; width:581.976pt; height:3pt; border:1px solid blue"> 
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  version="1.1" width="581.976pt" height="3pt" style="border:1px solid black; display: block;">
        <line id = "default" x1="0pt" y1="1.5pt" x2="581.976pt" y2="1.5pt" style="stroke:rgb(229,52,52); stroke-width:3pt;stroke-dasharray:10, 5"/> 
    </svg> 
</div>
```

Another alternative in this particular instance would be to float or position the SVG element, however this is a much-less versatile solution, and only indirectly solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Div position to `block` and float your svg element to `left`.

[working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/carunchandran/qL5p74xL/2/)